# Joomla in Azure - add VirtueMart, error 502

Tags: mysql, azure, joomla, virtuemart

I am using Joomla 3.3 and VirtueMart 3.0 on a Windows Azure Website. When I go to extension manager and install VirtueMart, I get this error:

502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server. There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

This is error log:

HTTP Error 1062.0 - Duplicate entry '251' for key 'PRIMARY' SQL=-- VirtueMart table data SQL script -- This will insert all essential data into the VirtueMart tables -- -- Configuration data has been moved to virtuemart.cfg -- -- -- Dumping data for table `jos_virtuemart_adminmenuentries` --

INSERT INTO `jos_virtuemart_adminmenuentries` (`id`, `module_id`, `parent_id`, `name`, `link`, `depends`, `icon_class`, `ordering`, `published`, `tooltip`, `view`, `task`) VALUES (null , 1, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_CATEGORY_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-folder_camera', 1, 1, '', 'category', ''), (null, 1, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-camera', 2, 1, '', 'product', ''), (null, 1, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_CUSTOM_FIELD_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-document_move', 5, 1, '', 'custom', ''), (null, 1, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PRODUCT_INVENTORY', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-price_watch', 7, 1, '', 'inventory', ''), (null, 1, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_CALC_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-calculator', 8, 1, '', 'calc', ''), (null, 1, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_REVIEW_RATE_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-comments', 9, 1, '', 'ratings', ''), (null, 2, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDER_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-page_white_stack', 1, 1, '', 'orders', ''), (null, 2, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_COUPON_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-shopping', 10, 1, '', 'coupon', ''), (null, 2, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_REPORT', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-chart_bar', 3, 1, '', 'report',''), (null, 2, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_USER_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-user', 4, 1, '', 'user', ''), (null, 2, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_SHOPPERGROUP_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-user-group', 5, 1, '', 'shoppergroup', ''), (null, 3, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_MANUFACTURER_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-wrench_orange', 1, 1, '', 'manufacturer', ''), (null, 3, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_MANUFACTURER_CATEGORY_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-folder_wrench', 2, 1, '', 'manufacturercategories', ''), (null, 4, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_STORE', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-reseller_account_template', 1, 1, '', 'user', 'editshop'), (null, 4, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_MEDIA_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-pictures', 2, 1, '', 'media', ''), (null, 4, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_SHIPMENTMETHOD_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-lorry', 3, 1, '', 'shipmentmethod', ''), (null, 4, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_PAYMENTMETHOD_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-creditcards', 4, 1, '', 'paymentmethod', ''), (null, 5, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_CONFIGURATION', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-config', 1, 1, '', 'config', ''), (null, 5, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_USERFIELD_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-participation_rate', 2, 1, '', 'userfields', ''), (null, 5, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_ORDERSTATUS_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-document_editing', 3, 1, '', 'orderstatus', ''), (null, 5, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_CURRENCY_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-coins', 5, 1, '', 'currency', ''), (null, 5, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_COUNTRY_S', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-globe', 6, 1, '', 'country', ''), (null, 11, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_MIGRATION_UPDATE', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-installer_box', 0, 1, '', 'updatesmigration', ''), (null, 11, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_ABOUT', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-info', 10, 1, '', 'about', ''), (null, 11, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_HELP_TOPICS', 'http://docs.virtuemart.net/', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-help', 5, 1, '', '', ''), (null, 11, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_COMMUNITY_FORUM', 'http://forum.virtuemart.net/', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-reseller_programm', 7, 1, '', '', ''), (null, 11, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_STATISTIC_SUMMARY', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-info', 1, 1, '', 'virtuemart', ''), (null, 11, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_LOG', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-info', 2, 1, '', 'log', ''), (null, 11, 0, 'COM_VIRTUEMART_SUPPORT', '', '', 'vmicon vmicon-16-help', 3, 1, '', 'support', '');

What do you advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I changed the script installation for table jos_virtuemart_adminmenuentries - replace null to uniquе  int value:

INSERT INTO `jos_virtuemart_adminmenuentries` (`id` ....

VALUES (1...